# Django: Proper method of totalling values from foreignkeys in related model

Tags: python, django, django-models, foreign-keys

I am not sure what the best practice way of totalling values from foreign key integer fields in the related model is. To give an example based on the django tutorial for building a library:

Say you've created your library of books and bookinstances with each book containing many real bookinstances that are in the library. You maintain an integerfield on BookInstance of number of times checked out. This way you can see how many times each specific instance has been checked out. Now you want to total all the times the instances have been checked out in the book model so you can have a quick reference for what book has been checked out the most in your library. What would be the best practice for totalling all of these values in the Book model?

I currently have a working solution for my case which stores an integerfield for number of times checked out on the book model itself and then I have a function in the book model that I call from the BookInstance Model:

```
def update_times_checked_out(self):
    instances = BookInstance.objects.filter(book__id = self.id)
    times_checked_out = 0
    for i in instances:
        times_checked_out += i.number_of_times_checked_out
    self.number_of_times_checked_out = times_checked_out
    self.save()
```

This works fine currently but I can imagine that with more and more BookInstances added to the database this could start to get really slow. I also know this will probably have a race condition if this is called twice at the same time by different BookInstances.

I know about F() expressions and use them in simple incrementing of +=1 situations but in my real world case this update wouldn't just handle constant value increments but also large jumps in value (could be +1/10/500 at any time from just 1 instance). Therefore I don't know how to use F() expressions properly to handle this.

Is there a better way to get the same result that I have currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Updating a *single* object

You can implement this with by making use of [**`Sum`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#sum):

```
from django.db.models import Sum

def update_times_checked_out(self):
    self.number_of_times_checked_out = BookInstance.objects.filter(
        book__id = self.id
    ).aggregate(
        checked_out=Sum('number_of_times_checked_out')
    )['checked_out']
    self.save()
```

Or if the `related_name` of the `BookInstance` foreign key to the current model is unchanged, we can even use:

```
from django.db.models import F, Sum

def update_times_checked_out(self):
    self.number_of_times_checked_out = self.book_instance_set.aggregate(
        checked_out=Sum('number_of_times_checked_out')
    )['checked_out']
    self.save()
```

We here thus sum up the `number_of_times_checked_out` of the related elements in a single query, and store this in our `number_of_times_checked_out`.

## Updating in *bulk*

If you want to update all the `number_of_times_checked_out` of this model at once, we can make a query with a subquery to perform the update in bulk:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery, Sum

MyModel.objects.update(
    number_of_times_checked_out=Subquery(
        BookInstance.objects.filter(
            book__id=OuterRef('id')
        ).annotate(
            checked_out=Sum('number_of_times_checked_out')
        ).values('checked_out')[:1]
    )
)
```

Here all `MyModel` objects will thus update the `number_of_times_checked_out` field in a single query. Of course that query will be more *expensive* than a query for a single object, but usually several times faster than updating each object with the above method individually.

You can, like [@BradMartsberger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56134918/django-proper-method-of-totalling-values-from-foreignkeys-in-related-model/56134949#comment98984627_56134949) says, also make use of the `django-sql-utils` package, and then work with `SubquerySum`, like:

```
from sql_util.utils import SubquerySum

MyModel.objects.update(
    number_of_times_checked_out=SubquerySum('bookinstance__checked_out')
)
```

Comment: Good answer, just wanted to point at that the django-sql-utils (https://pypi.org/project/django-sql-utils/) package simplifies the subquery so you can just have `number_of_times_checked_out=SubquerySum('book')`